# What does the "Type" mean in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, types

I am totally confused by Elasticsearch's documents.

In [Basic Concepts: Type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_basic_concepts.html#_type), "type" are somehow like collections in MongoDB:

> In this index, you may define a type for user data, another type for blog data, and yet another type for comments data.

But in [Types and Mappings: Type Takeaways](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping.html#_type_takeaways), it says:

> Types are not as well suited for entirely different types of data. If your two types have mutually exclusive sets of fields, that means half your index is going to contain "empty" values (the fields will be sparse), which will eventually cause performance problems.

Doesn't "user" and "blog" above mentioned have mutually exclusive sets of fields?
For example: there are "name", "age" fields for "user", and "createdAt", "content" for "blog".

I'm used to believe the mapping relation between Elasticsearch and MongoDB is:

index <=> database

type <=> collection

isn't it right?
If not, what is the recommended mapping style between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Types are not as well suited for entirely different types of data. If your two types have mutually exclusive sets of fields, that means half your index is going to contain "empty" values (the fields will be sparse), which will eventually cause performance problems.

The `type` is just another field in Elasticsearch, at the very basic level. When you do `GET /my_index/my_type/_search` ES will run a pre-filter for `my_type` value for field `_type` - it's like an automatic filter.

Don't think about indices and types as databases and tables in SQL world, because they are not that.

If you have `type1` with fields `f1` and `f2` and `type2` with fields `f1` and `f3` in the index there will be documents with fields `f1`, `f2`, `f3`. Why this matters - when the score for a document will be calculated with queries that search for values in field `f1` the terms frequencies in field `f1` will be **global** (both `type1` and `type2`) so if you search some value in `f1` from `type1` then the score you get back is slightly influenced, also, by the values of `f1` in `type2`.

Also, please, don't translate a set of SQL tables to ES by simply following the primary key/foreign key approach to define parent/child relationships in ES.

Comment: So "user" and "blog" should be put in different indices, or different types in one index?

Comment: It depends on the data: do you need the relationship between them in queries? Will there be more blogs belonging to a user? How many? How complex is the user? It is so simple that you can put it in the same index and type so that you can simply duplicate data? Btw, in ES world many times is much better to have denormalized data (like putting the same user data in each blog the user owns).

Answer (score -1):

You're right, index == database and type == collection for elasticsearch. In RDBMS terms, `index` is a database and `type` can be a table which contains many rows(`document` in elasticsearch).

You could have a different index maintaining user information, with the "name",  "age" and other such fields generally attributed to a person, and a different one for blogs with "createdAt", "content", etc. Yet, you might want to have a "user" field inside each blog document to be able to identify the person who posted it. Later, you can apply [application-side joins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html), if need be.

Comment: In the past we tried to make elasticsearch easier to understand by building an analogy with relational databases: indices would be like a database, and types like a table in a database. This was a mistake: the way data is stored is so different that any comparisons can hardly make sense, and this ultimately led to an overuse of types in cases where they were more harmful than helpful. 

[elasticsearch blog post index-vs-type](https://www.elastic.co/es/blog/index-vs-type)